# Get a value of an attribute in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here's my code:

```
a1.superclass
=> ApplicationRecord(abstract)
```

Also I have the name of an attribute as a string. How can I get its value? This doesn't work:

```
a1.send(attr1)
a1[attr1]
```

This does, but it returns Hash:

```
 a1.attribute(attr1)


=> {"my_super_attr"=>[#<ActiveModel::Type::Value:0x0055b83c524ac8 @precision=nil, @scale=nil, @limit=nil>, {}]}
```

How can I retrieve the actual value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a1.superclass` returns `ApplicationRecord(abstract)`, this means that `a1` is a class and not an actual record. You can't read a value from a class since it's not an instance. If you do something like `a1.first[attr1]`, everything should work just fine.

Comment: also, 1) a1.first --> the 1st **record**, correct? 2) how can I iterate over them? I've tried "each" and [], but they didn't work.

Comment: To fetch multiple records, you need to do `NameOfTheClass.all` or use any other scope/Arel method (e.g. `NameOfTheClass.order(title: :asc)`). Then you can use `each`.